# Replace muli user FTP accounts with PHP upload script (upload files from Windows app)

Tags: php, ftp, upload

Until our webhost suddenly sold itself to a competitor without cpanel we had the following solution:

We supplied a Windows app to a customer where they could change data and upload to pre-defined FTP path through their own FTP account. (Hence they could never access/tamper with other customers data) - e.g. ftp://example.com/data/customer1/ - We would then have their app automatically download new data (images XML etc.) from the webserver http://example.com/data/customer1/

We can either move webhost or change our solution:

We could code the Windows app to upload files over HTTP I suppose - but we would need a PHP solution that could verify user account and accept file uploads. My problem is... Even if we develop that ourselves- is such a solution future proof?

- Is there any existing solution we can use that fits our needs?
- Is it likely PHP file upload will continue working? And on most webservers and https:// and future "best practices" security changes?

I am particular interested in hearing if I have thought through potential problems - as I have not worked with HTTP file upload before, I am not sure how well such a solution will work in the real life.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP file upload is used in many places, for example on all big social media platforms. So, it is definitely stable.

I would also say that PHP support will stay in the future, since its user-base is so big. However, differences between versions might stay.

I'm sure you can find many implementations of upload forms in the internet. Just use your favourite search engine to find a suitable one. I don't know any particular solution, and even if I did, it is off-topic over here.